# Android Fragments not being recreated on Activity Restart

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Activity which contains a couple of nested Fragments. I have been having a lot of trouble handling orientation changes. Something is not correct when the Activity tries to recreate itself which causes the app to crash. If I try to debug the code during an orientation change the app crashes without any messages in the logcat.

My problem seems to be the the runtime is trying to recreate the fragments in my Activity when I don't want it to. None of the fragments have setRetainInstance(true) so they shouldn't be getting kept.

I have added logging to the onCreate and onDestroy methods of the Activity and Fragments. When the app first runs I get the following output:

```
Activity onCreate
Fragment1 onCreate
Fragment1 onCreateViewStart
Fragment1 onCreateViewEnd
Fragment2 onCreate
Fragment2 onCreateViewStart
Fragment2 onCreateViewEnd
```

I then rotate the device and get the following:

```
Fragment1 onDestroy
Fragment2 onDestroy
Activity onDestroy
Fragment1 onCreate
Fragment2 onCreate
Activity onCreate
Fragment1 onCreateViewStart
Fragment1 onCreateViewEnd
Fragment2 onCreateViewStart
Fragment2 onCreateViewEnd
Fragment2 onDestroy
Fragment2 onCreate
```

After the last message above the app crashes with the following exception message:

```
E/FragmentManager(32258): No view found for id 0x7f0a0047 (com.appName:id/fragmentHolder) for fragment Fragment2{6529b910 #6 id=0x7f0a0047 16002}
```

Why are my fragments being recreated automatically? Is there anything I can do to force the activity to reload as if the app was being started for the first time when the orientation changes? Is this not how the life cycle is supposed to work in the first place?

I can add any code if requested.

Comment: Are resources/layouts correct? Is logic on onCreateView correct? I would not blame Android and first take a very close look at your code and layouts.

Comment: As far as I can tell they are. Everything works fine if I limit the orientation to either Portrait or Landscape. If there is an issue in the onCreateView code then I don't understand why it is not be caught by the catch block.



What I don't understand is why the fragments are being recreated automatically rather than recreated the activity in its original state and then reloading the fragments from there.

Comment: **"I can add any code if requested."** : That's kind of how we work around here. It's hard to give a solution unless you show code being used to create your `Activity` and `Fragments`.

Answer (score 1):

- The `FragmentManager` is responsible for managing the fragments and
  adding them to the activity's view hierarchy.
- The `FragmentManager` handles two things:

  - A list of fragments.
  - back stack of fragment transactions.
- To *add*, *remove*, *attach*, *detach* or *replace* fragments in the fragment list you use `Fragment Transactions`.
- When you ask the FragmentManager for a fragment using `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`, if the fragment is
  already in the list, the FragmentManager will return it. Then you can
  use it.

Knowing that. If there are fragments added to the FragmentManager's list when the orientation change happens, those fragments are going to be recreated automatically in order to recreate the view hierarchy as it was before the orientation change. If you don't want a fragment to be recreated, remove it from the list using a fragment transaction.

Comment: It looks like if I remove the last item in the backstack (if there is one) I'm able to reload my activity without the crash. I should be able to recreate the requires fragments from there. I'll give that a go

Answer (score 0):

You know how if you background an app and then reopen it? The Activity instances are still there with the `Bundle savedInstanceState` populated with data. This means that the OS is recreating your app from a serialised state rather than from scratch.

What you need to do in the case where `savedInstanceState` is not null is look use your `FragmentManager` to `findFragmentByTag`.